# From point-wise to essential supremum of a set of real-valued measurable functions

Tags: measure-theory

For an uncountable collection of uncountable sets of real-valued random variables (i.e. measurable with respect to a $\sigma$-algebra) $\{S_i\}_{i\in I}$, with

$\inf \left(\bigcap_{i\in I}S_i \right)= \sup\{\inf S_i|{i\in I}\}$

I want to to show

$\mathrm{ess}\inf \left(\bigcap_{i\in I}S_i \right)= \mathrm{ess}\sup\{\mathrm{ess}\inf S_i|{i\in I}\}$

I tried something in analogy to the [proof of existence of the essential supremum](https://planetmath.org/proofofexistenceoftheessentialsupremum), but failed.

It would be great to get some help on this. Does it hold and if so, how prove it and if not, why not?

---

This is a cross-posting from [this question on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304696/from-point-wise-to-essential-supremum-of-a-set-of-real-valued-measurable-functio) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20151024010145/http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304696/from-point-wise-to-essential-supremum-of-a-set-of-real-valued-measurable-functio))

---

Edit: I change the notation. No the all infima/suprema are understood to be pointwise suprema of a set of functions. And the essential suprema/infima of a set of functions should be read like on [this page](https://planetmath.org/essentialsupremum).

The indexed intersection is defined as usual: $\bigcap_{i\in I}S_i = \{x|\forall i\in I: x\in S_i\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. Give $[0,1]$ Lebesgue measure. For each $t \in [0,1]$ let $S_t = \{1_{\{t\}}\} \cup \{a\cdot 1_{[0,1]}: a \geq 1\}$.

Then $\bigcap S_t = \{a\cdot 1_{[0,1]}: a \geq 1\}$ and its inf is the function $1_{[0,1]}$. For each $t$ the inf of $S_t$ is the function $1_{\{t\}}$, and the sup of these is also the function $1_{[0,1]}$. So your premise holds.

The essential inf of $\bigcap S_t$ is also the function $1_{[0,1]}$ but the essential inf of each $S_t$ is the zero function and their essential sup is again the zero function. So the conclusion fails.

Is this really what you meant?

Comment: Nice, yes that's what he's asking (I think).

Comment: thanks for the (embarassingly easy) example. What I am actually after: I want to find out the conditions for the second equation. I thought, solving the question for the first equation would help. Here, a sufficient condition seems to be that the sets are upper sets. But I have no clue how to show the same for "almost surely upper sets". The greatest obstacle is, that I do not know how to handle the set of measurable functions ordered by $\le$ (a.s.), because it fails to be the simple product order. What properties does it share with the product order? (e.g. complete distributivity: No, ...)

Comment: If the $S_i$ are upper sets, then the equation you are asking for IS complete distributivity.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not clear. Are you asking whether the complete distributive law holds in (probably the unit ball of) $L^\infty(X,\mu)$? The answer is no: complete distributivity is characteristic of atomic measure spaces. An easy way to see this is to use the fact that a complete lattice is completely distributive iff it has the property that for all $c$ and $d$ with $c \not\geq d$ there exist $c' \not\leq c$ and $d' \not\geq d$ such that every element of the lattice lies above $c'$ or below $d'$. I refer you to Theorem 6.42 of my book *Lipschitz Algebras* (second edition) for a proof. Let $A$ be a positive measure set that contains no atoms, find $B \subset A$ with $0 < \mu(B) < \mu(A)$, and take $c = \chi_B$ and $d = \chi_{A\setminus B}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are the equations in my questions equivalent to the complete distributive law? I ultimately want to know, under what conditions for $S_i$ the equation for the ess inf/sup holds. After I found a condition for the inf/sup equation I am now trying to transfer it to the ess inf/sup and do not know, if this makes sense at all.

Comment: What order relation are you talking about? Product order for real-valued functions?

Comment: How can a $c′$ exists, such that every element of the lattice lies above it, if also $c′ \nleq c$? Doesn't "above" mean $c′\le c$? – Johannes 0 secs ago

Comment: @Johannes: (1) it's hard for me to tell exactly what the equations in your question are supposed to mean.  I am guessing. (2) $f \leq g$ if $f(x) \leq g(x)$ except on a set of measure zero. (3) every element of the lattice either lies above $c'$ or lies below $d'$.

Comment: ok. I tried to make the notation more clear. Is it understandable now?